# Having a button increment an array each time it is clicked

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, button

I'm tasked with having a button that will set a value entered to an array. The user will enter a value press the button, once the button is pressed the value the user entered is stored into an array. My teacher (yes this is a homework question) said that he wants it to do only one value at a time.

The problem i'm running into is, I just don't know what to write in order for this to happen. I've tried looking at what all I can do in the event but that has gotten me nowhere, unless the answer was there and I just completely missed it.

Any suggestions on where to look, or an idea of what to write would be awesome.

```
private void addToArray_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button bclick = (Button) sender;

    string variables = addArrayTextBox.Text;
    int []vars = new int[5];
    vars = parseVariableString(variables);
    int numberIndex = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < vars.Length; i++)
    {
        int indexNumber = vars.Length;
        numberIndex = indexNumber;
    }
    integerTextBox.Text = numberIndex.ToString();
}
```

Is what I currently have typed up.

Comment: your requirement is unclear.  Could you please read over your question, and then more clearly describe what you have to do?

Comment: What does `parseVariableString()` do?

Comment: if it's homework, than do you have a written definition of your assignment?

Comment: @Samiam I have edited the question. Hopefully it is more clear.

Comment: @Fuex: parseVariableString() is method that I set up in order to parse the variables being entered. I realize that with the question that I am tasked with it is not needed.

Comment: @SamIam: This is what the assignment states:

c.  The integer values are entered, one at a time into the text box next to the “Add to Array” button. After each value is entered, the “Add to Array” button is pressed.
d.  The following occurs when the “Add To Array” button is pressed:
i.  The value entered into the “Add To Array” text box is added to the array.
ii.  The “Add To Array” text box is cleared.
iii.  The value of the “Integers Entered” text box is incremented by one. For example, after the third integer is entered into the “Add To Array” text box and

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get you started

let's get the graphical designer stuff out of the way first:

1. make your winforms project
2. drag and drop a button
3. drag and drop a text box
4. double-click on the button to create a `button_click` event handler

next, you'll probably want your array to stay in scope, the simplest way to do that is to declare it as a field of your `Form1` instance, and then instantiate and/or initialize it in the `Form1 Constructor.

Then you can access it from your event handler

**example:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int[] vars;
    int intergersEntered;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        vars = new int[5];
        intergersEntered = 0;
        // insert other initialization here
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       vars[0] = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
       intergersEntered++;
       textBox2.Text = intergersEntered.ToString();
    }
...
```

Comment: Thank you so very much. I was definitely over thinking the problem at hand.

Comment: Doesn't this method overwrite the first index of the array each time?  My reading of the assignment is to "add the value to the array".  So each time the array will increase in size by one and the newly entered value added to that new index.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway it's not intended to be a complete project.  It's just there to give the OP the basic framework he needs.  I might as well have written `\\do something with the array here`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I get your question based on your code. Paraphrasing, you want to increase an array length by 1 when a button is pressed, yes?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int[] vars;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        vars = new int[5];
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int[] tmp = new int[vars.Length + 1];
        vars.CopyTo(tmp, 0);
        vars = tmp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you need to just resize the array to one higher each time the "Add To Array" button is clicked:

```
private void addToArray_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //Calculate the new size of the array
    int newLength = arrayOfIntegers.Length + 1;

    //Resize the array
    Array.Resize(ref arrayOfIntegers, newLength);

    //Add the new value to the array
    //Note that this will fail if the textbox does not contain a valid integer.  
    //You can use the Integer.TryParse method to handle this
    arrayOfIntegers[newLength] = Integer.Parse(addArrayTextBox.Text);  

    //Update the text box with the new count
    integerTextBox.Text = newLength.ToString();
}
```